# Spring JavaMailSender with MS Exchange :java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.sun.mail.uti.maillogger

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send mail from Spring web application and unsuccessfully in production but success in UAT. This Spring web application deployed on Tomcat server through port 25 with no authentication, no SSL.

Error
**java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.sun.mail.uti.maillogger**

important

**abcd.com is internal domain zxc.com is external domain**

I'm using:

**Spring - 4.2.6.RELEASE 
javax.mail-api - 1.5.5 
mail - 1.4.1**

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {

JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        // Using PROD.
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.abcd.com");
        mailSender.setPort(25);
        mailSender.setUsername("imsdc@abcd.com");
        mailSender.setPassword("test017");

        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false"); 
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true"); //

        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);

     return mailSender;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger` is a part of JavaMail API [1], existing in Java EE (web application server).

`com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger` is not existing in Java SE.

Maybe, UAT use Java EE, therefore success.
Production use Tomcat without JavaMail, therefore fail.

Solution: Download, add JavaMail dependency to your production environment [2] (Put JavaMail jar dependency to `%CATALINA_HOME%\lib`, or add JavaMail dependency by Maven pom.xml file)

[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html
[2] https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release

Comment: thank you very much for your comments, I'm going to try 2nd option first.

Comment: I hope u asking to put this jar(javax.mail-1.6.0.jar)...
jar file -javax.mail.jar,  groupId -com.sun.mail artifactId -javax.mail Description -The JavaMail reference implementation jar file, including the SMTP, IMAP, and POP3 protocol providers

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/mail/Session"

Comment: In Maven *pom.xml*, scope of JavaMail dependency is `provided`, not `compiled` (default).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the dependency is not being found (maybe because it is not in the JRE environment). Try adding this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I used javax.mail-1.5.5.jar. after use that I'm getting this, 
Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client

Comment: You've solved this problem.  Post a new question with the details of the new problem.  Include the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).